# split a list into three lists with a stepsize and a starting point

Tags: python, list

I have a list which looks like below.

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 .....]
```

and i want to split it into three lists which will have below values.

```
first_list = [1, 4, 7, ...]
second_list = [2, 5, 8,....]
third_list = [3, 6, 9, ...]
```

I do not want to split it into three equal sized chunks and want the lists to be split as above. Any help is useful.

Thanks

Comment: In addition to the example, could you tell us by what rule you'd like the numbers distributed? Or is this like an SAT question where we're supposed to guess?

Comment: if not equal chunks, how do you determine where to split?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the slice notation by changing the start value and setting a step value:

```
l[start:end:step]
```

---

```
In [1]: l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

In [2]: [l[start::3] for start in range(3)]
Out[2]: [[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```

---

To assign the lists to variables:

```
first_list, second_list, third_list = [l[i::3]for i in range(3)]
```

Comment: You can also do this straight away: `first_list, second_list, third_list = [l[i::3]for i in range(3)]`

Comment: Thanks very much. This is exactly what i am looking for. Apologies for misleading text in my question.

Answer (score 5):

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
print (my_list[0::3])
print (my_list[1::3])
print (my_list[2::3])

--output:--
[1, 4, 7]
[2, 5, 8]
[3, 6, 9]
```

Also, never use list for a variable name.  Until you know what you are doing, put 'my' in front of all your variable names.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but it does give you the output you're asking for, so:

First, use the `grouper` function in the [`itertools` recipes](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes):

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
groups = grouper(lst, 3)
a, b, c = zip(*groups)
```

If you understand how `grouper` works, it's just zipping together 3 copies of an iterator made from `lst`, so you can simplify this to:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
it = iter(lst)
a, b, c = zip(*zip(it, it, it))
```

Comment: Last line should be `a, b, c = zip(*zip(it, it, it))`.

Answer (score 1):

With uneven sized groups, you can distribute the sequence vertically into `n` many separate lists and use a sentinel value to leave the remaining list with shorter than `n` values...

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

from itertools import izip_longest
sentinel = object()
grouped = zip(*izip_longest(*[iter(lst)] * 3, fillvalue=sentinel))
list1, list2, list3 = ([el for el in obj if el is not sentinel] for obj in grouped)
print list1, list2, list3
# [1, 4, 7] [2, 5, 8] [3, 6]
```

Comment: This is a great use of `object()` as a sentinel value. +1

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = range(10)
def condition1(x):
    return x%3 == 1

def condition2(x):
    return x%3 == 2

L1,L2,L3 = [],[],[]
#[L1.append(x) if condition1(x) else L2.append(x) if condition2(x) else L3.append(x) for x in my_list]
#made above list comprehension more readable by switching it to a for loop
for item in list:
    if condition1(item): 
         L1.append(item)
    elif condition2(item):
         L2.append(item)
    else:
         L3.append(item)
print L1
print L2
print L3
```

Comment: This is a horrible abuse of list comprehensions.

Comment: I don't even.. Why would you split up the conditionals like that?

Comment: Well, if I were taking a class, and suspected the prof didn't really understand Python, I would definitely turn in something like this for homework to test him. Except I'd probably also make `condition1` and `condition2` into lambdas generated by a single function, instead of two separate `def` statements. (When I was in college a few centuries ago, I had similar fun with a prof teaching "Data Structures in C" who didn't know C.)

Comment: based on op's question this is what i thought matched :P ... but yeah it woulda been better in a for loop (for readability)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want them split with respect to the index or the element value?

If it's by element value you could do something like this (filtering using modulus by three):

```
list = range(1,10)

first_list = filter(lambda x: x % 3 == 1, list)
second_list = filter(lambda x: x % 3 == 2, list)
third_list = filter(lambda x: x % 3 == 0, list)
```

If it's by index you use slice notation:

```
list = range(1,10)

first_list = list[::3]
second_list = list[1::3]
third_list = list[2::3]
```

Check out the documentation on [filter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) and [lambda's](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#lambda) (along with other awesome [builtins](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html)).